# Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, debugging, error-handling, warnings

#### What is this?

This is a number of answers about warnings, errors, and notices you might encounter while programming PHP and have no clue how to fix them. This is also a Community Wiki, so everyone is invited to participate adding to and maintaining this list.

#### Why is this?

Questions like ["Headers already sent"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12770075) or ["Calling a member of a non-object"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12769983) pop up frequently on Stack Overflow. The root cause of those questions is always the same. So the answers to those questions typically repeat them and then show the OP which line to change in their particular case. These answers do not add any value to the site because they only apply to the OP's particular code. Other users having the same error cannot easily read the solution out of it because they are too localized. That is sad because once you understood the root cause, fixing the error is trivial. Hence, this list tries to explain the solution in a general way to apply.

#### What should I do here?

If your question has been marked as a duplicate of this one, please find your error message below and apply the fix to your code. The answers usually contain further links to investigate in case it shouldn't be clear from the general answer alone.

If you want to contribute, please add your "favorite" error message, warning or notice, one per answer, a short description what it means (even if it is only highlighting terms to their manual page), a possible solution or debugging approach and a listing of existing Q&A that are of value. Also, feel free to improve any existing answers.

### The List

- [Nothing is seen. The page is empty and white.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12772851) (also known as *White Page/Screen Of Death*)
- [Code doesn't run/what looks like parts of my PHP code are output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24423272)
- [Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12770075)
- [Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12770072) a.k.a.
  [Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12770072)
- [Warning: *[function]* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14067623)
- [Warning: *[function]*: failed to open stream: *[reason]*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12820243)
- [Warning: open_basedir restriction in effect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12772244)
- [Warning: Division by zero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21507314)
- [Warning: Illegal string offset 'XXX'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27678436)
- [Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56011600)
- [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22316776)
- [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_XXX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12770089)
- [Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13935532)
- [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12770129)
- [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'require_once' (T_REQUIRE_ONCE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23726288)
- [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15539535)
- [Fatal error: Allowed memory size of XXX bytes exhausted (tried to allocate XXX bytes)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12770179)
- [Fatal error: Maximum execution time of XX seconds exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73082532)
- [Fatal error: Call to a member function ... on a non-object or null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12769983)
- [Fatal Error: Call to Undefined function XXX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12784048)
- [Fatal Error: Cannot redeclare XXX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13879461)
- [Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12770530)
- [Fatal error: Declaration of AAA::BBB() must be compatible with that of CCC::BBB()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1885302)'
- [Return type of AAA::BBB() should either be compatible with CCC::BBB(), or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71133749)
- [Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12770317)
- [Fatal error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56658110)
- [Fatal error: Undefined class constant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59619392/1255289)
- [Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument #n must be of type x, y given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67781316)
- [Notice: Array to string conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24507107) (< PHP 8.0) or [Warning: Array to string conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24507107) (>= PHP 8.0)
- [Notice: Trying to get property of non-object error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26572398)
- [Notice: Undefined variable or property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12778634)
- ["Notice: Undefined Index", or "Warning: Undefined array key"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12770836)
- [Notice: Undefined offset XXX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21793407) [Reference]
- [Notice: Uninitialized string offset: XXX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17630869)
- [Notice: Use of undefined constant XXX - assumed 'XXX' / Error: Undefined constant XXX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12773272)
- [MySQL: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ... at line ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12771239)
- [Strict Standards: Non-static method *[<class>::<method>]* should not be called statically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21942832)
- [Warning: function expects parameter X to be boolean/string/integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52771226)
- [HTTP Error 500 - Internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53843354)
- [Deprecated: Arrays and strings offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59158847)
- [Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, <type> given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77934648/6196568)

Also, see:

- [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139)

Comment: Also, to move discussion out of comments, please go to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149743/php-errors-reference-question) meta question

Comment: X-Ref: [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18050071/367456); Elsewhere: [Common PHP Errors and Solutions](http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/common-php-errors-solution_t)

Comment: see this http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/30/a-guide-to-php-error-messages-for-designers/   and this also http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Errors_and_symptoms

Comment: X-Ref: [Fixing PHP Errors (May 2013; by Jason McCreary)](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/05/fixing-php-errors/)

Answer (score 304):

#### Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Happens when your script tries to send an HTTP header to the client but there already was output before, which resulted in headers to be already sent to the client.

This is an [`E_WARNING`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) and it will not stop the script.

A typical example would be a template file like this:

```
<html>
    <?php session_start(); ?>
    <head><title>My Page</title>
</html>
...
```

The `session_start()` function will try to send headers with the session cookie to the client. But PHP already sent headers when it wrote the `<html>` element to the output stream. You'd have to move the `session_start()` to the top.

You can solve this by going through the lines *before* the code triggering the Warning and check where it outputs. Move any header sending code before that code.

An often overlooked output is new lines after PHP's closing `?>`. It is considered a standard practice to omit `?>` when it is the last thing in the file. Likewise, another common cause for this warning is when the opening `<?php` has an empty space, line, or invisible character before it, causing the web server to send the headers and the whitespace/newline thus when PHP starts parsing won't be able to submit any header.

If your file has more than one `<?php ... ?>` code block in it, you should not have any spaces in between them. (Note: You might have multiple blocks if you had code that was automatically constructed)

Also make sure you don't have any Byte Order Marks in your code, for example when the encoding of the script is UTF-8 with BOM.

Related Questions:

- [Headers already sent by PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)
- [All PHP "Headers already sent" Questions on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=headers+already+sent+[php])
- [Byte Order Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=BOM+php)
- [What PHP Functions Create Output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673747/what-php-functions-create-output)

Comment: If you are using WordPress, check the theme files. When I upgraded a site to a new version of WordPress, I was unable to update the theme because it has not been updated in several years. This problem cropped up. It turned out that the functions.php file had more than one <? ?> block with spaces in between.

Comment: @RoyLeban "If your file has more than one block in it..." I'm not sure what this means. What is a "block"? Would one block consist of `<?php ?>` and so "more than one block" would be `<?php ?>     <?php ?>`?

Comment: Please turn on 'output buffering' feature in PHP.ini configuration file if possible.It is used for sloving this issue.It sends the html file is saved in the output buffer and sent to the client only after the script stops, so if two headers are issued at different location then the old header will be replaced new header.

Answer (score 207):

#### Fatal error: Call to a member function ... on a non-object

Happens with code similar to `xyz->method()` where `xyz` is not an object and therefore that `method` can not be called.

This is a fatal error which will stop the script (forward compatibility notice: It will become a catchable error starting with PHP 7).

Most often this is a sign that the code has missing checks for error conditions. Validate that an object is actually an object before calling its methods.

A [typical](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%5Bpdo%5D+Fatal+error%3A+Call+to+a+member+function+on+a+non-object) example would be

```
// ... some code using PDO
$statement = $pdo->prepare('invalid query', ...);
$statement->execute(...);
```

In the example above, the query cannot be prepared and `prepare()` will assign `false` to `$statement`. Trying to call the `execute()` method will then result in the Fatal Error because `false` is a "non-object" because the value is a boolean.

Figure out *why* your function returned a boolean instead of an object. For example, check the `$pdo` object for the last error that occurred. Details on how to debug this will depend on how errors are handled for the particular function/object/class in question.

If even the `->prepare` is failing then your `$pdo` database handle object [didn't get passed into the current scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910796/scope-error-call-to-a-member-function-prepare-on-a-non-object). Find where it got defined. Then pass it as a parameter, store it as property, or share it via the global scope.

Another problem may be conditionally creating an object and then trying to call a method outside that conditional block. For example

```
if ($someCondition) {
    $myObj = new MyObj();
}
// ...
$myObj->someMethod();
```

By attempting to execute the method outside the conditional block, your object may not be defined.

Related Questions:

- [Call to a member function on a non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54566/727208)
- [List all PHP "Fatal error: Call to a member function ... on a non-object" Questions on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+Fatal+error%3A+Call+to+a+member+function+on+a+non-object)

Answer (score 130):

#### Nothing is seen. The page is empty and white.

Also known as the *White Page Of Death* or *White Screen Of Death*. This happens when error reporting is turned off and a fatal error (often syntax error) occurred.

If you have error logging enabled, you will find the concrete error message in your error log. This will usually be in a file called "php_errors.log", either in a central location (e.g. `/var/log/apache2` on many Linux environments) or in the directory of the script itself (sometimes used in a shared hosting environment).

Sometimes it might be more straightforward to temporarily enable the display of errors. The white page will then display the error message. Take care because these errors are visible  to everybody visiting the website.

This can be easily done by adding at the top of the script the following PHP code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(~0);
```

The code will turn on the display of errors and set reporting to the highest level.

Since the [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/ini_set) is executed at runtime it has no effects on parsing/syntax errors. Those errors will appear in the log. If you want to display them in the output as well (e.g. in a browser) you have to set the [`display_startup_errors`](http://php.net/display_startup_errors) directive to `true`. Do this either in the `php.ini` or in a `.htaccess` or by [any other method that affects the configuration *before* runtime](http://docs.php.net/configuration.changes).

You can use the same methods to set the [log_errors](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors) and [error_log](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) directives to choose your own log file location.

Looking in the log or using the display, you will get a much better error message and the line of code where your script comes to halt.

Related questions:

- [PHP's white screen of death](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death)
- [White screen of death!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914127/white-screen-of-death)
- [PHP Does Not Display Error Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680831/php-5-3-does-not-display-error-messages)
- [PHP emitting 500 on errors - where is this documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3075355/367456)
- [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)
- [All PHP "White Page of Death" Questions on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+White+Page+Screen+Of+Death)

Related errors:

- [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_XXX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12770089/#12770089)
- [Fatal error: Call to a member function ... on a non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12769983#12769983)
- [Code doesn't run/what looks like parts of my PHP code are output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24423272/476)

Comment: `error_reporting(~0);` why not `-1`? That is what `~0` evaluates to, and is much less cryptic.

Comment: I think both are similarly cryptic. `~0` is more explicit IMO: negate the empty bit set, i. e. enable **all** flags. -1 is not meant to stand for «not found» like in strpos() in C, but as a bitset with all flags set, because -1 is binary `1111'1111'1111'1111` (for 32 bits).

Comment: Oops, `1111'1111'1111'1111` is really 16 bits, but I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Another reason you might have got this is because you put `return false;` in your PHP code

Answer (score 112):

#### "Notice: Undefined Index", or "Warning: Undefined array key"

Happens when you try to access an array by a key that does not exist in the array.

A typical example of an `Undefined Index` notice would be ([demo](http://codepad.org/bsoiXSzw))

```
$data = array('foo' => '42', 'bar');
echo $data['spinach'];
echo $data[1];
```

Both `spinach` and `1` do not exist in the array, causing an [`E_NOTICE`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) to be triggered. In PHP 8.0, this is an E_WARNING instead.

The solution is to make sure the index or offset exists prior to accessing that index. This may mean that you need to fix a bug in your program to ensure that those indexes do exist when you expect them to. Or it may mean that you need to test whether the indexes exist using [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/array_key_exists) or [`isset`](http://php.net/isset):

```
$data = array('foo' => '42', 'bar');
if (array_key_exists('spinach', $data)) {
    echo $data['spinach'];
}
else {
    echo 'No key spinach in the array';
}
```

If you have code like:

```
<?php echo $_POST['message']; ?>
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="message">
    ...
```

then `$_POST['message']` will not be set when this page is first loaded and you will get the above error. Only when the form is submitted and this code is run a second time will the array index exist. You typically check for this with:

```
if ($_POST)  ..  // if the $_POST array is not empty
// or
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') ..  // page was requested with POST
```

Related Questions:

- [Reference: “Notice: Undefined variable” and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)
- [All PHP "Notice: Undefined Index" Questions on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+undefined+index)
- http://php.net/arrays

Comment: I tend to use `if(!empty($_POST['message'])){ //do stuff }`

Answer (score 94):

#### Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

First and foremost:

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

---

This happens when you try to fetch data from the result of `mysql_query` but the query failed.

This is a warning and won't stop the script, but will make your program wrong.

You need to check the result returned by `mysql_query` by

```
$res = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$res) {
   trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
}
// after checking, do the fetch
```

Related Questions:

- [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)
- [All "mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given" Questions on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Warning:%20mysql_fetch_array%28%29%20expects%20parameter%201%20to%20be%20resource&submit=search)

Related Errors:

- [Warning: *[function]* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/14067623#14067623)

Other `mysql*` functions that also expect a MySQL result resource as a parameter will produce the same error for the same reason.

Comment: Just a note. If `mysql_query` isn't bad enough, adding `or die` on top of it is adding insult to injury.

Comment: The problem I encounter is `$res = mysql_query($query)` returns 1 if query is successful so it is considered true. Therefore when passing the result of  `mysql_query ` to  `mysql_fetch_array()`  the notice shows.

Comment: @mboy For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.

For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.

Comment: @xdazz That is the problem I am facing, Insert update returns TRUE so I cannot get rid of this error `mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select`

please see - https://gist.github.com/romelemperado/93af4cdbd44ebf3a07cbfa0e3fc539d7

Any suggestion to git rid of this error?

Comment: @mboy `mysql_fetch_array()` is for select query, for insert and update, you don't need to fetch the result set (and there is no result set let you fetch).

Comment: @xdazz Thanks! Anyway I updated to to this - https://gist.github.com/romelemperado/93af4cdbd44ebf3a07cbfa0e3fc539d7

and no more errors..

Answer (score 86):

#### Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

[`$this` is a special variable in PHP](http://php.net/language.variables.basics) which can not be assigned. If it is accessed in a context where it does not exist, this fatal error is given.

This error can occur:

1. If a non-static method is called statically. Example:

   ```
   class Foo {
      protected $var;
      public function __construct($var) {
          $this->var = $var;
      }

      public static function bar () {
          // ^^^^^^
          echo $this->var;
          //   ^^^^^
      }
   }

   Foo::bar();
   ```

   ***How to fix:*** review your code again, `$this` can only be used in an object context, and should never be used in a static method. Also, a static method should not access the non-static property. Use `self::$static_property` to access the static property.
2. If code from a class method has been copied over into a normal function or just the global scope *and* keeping the `$this` special variable.
   ***How to fix:*** Review the code and replace `$this` with a different substitution variable.

Related Questions:

1. Call non-static method as static: [PHP Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2350937/367456)
2. Copy over code: [Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1643931/367456)
3. [All "Using $this when not in object context" Questions on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Fatal%20error:%20Using%20$this%20when%20not%20in%20object%20context)

Comment: You might also want to mention how this works w/ closures (even in non-static methods) and how it's "fixed" in 5.4.

Comment: @hakre I was talking about a static call inside a Closure. Like `$closure = function() { self::method(); }`.

Comment: @KendallHopkins: That is a different error: *"Fatal error: Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active"* However with `$this` you can trigger the bespoken *"Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context"* : `$closure = function() { $this->method(); };`

Answer (score 82):

#### Fatal error: Call to undefined function XXX

Happens when you try to call a function that is not defined yet. Common causes include missing extensions and includes, conditional function declaration, function in a function declaration or simple typos.

**Example 1 - Conditional Function Declaration**

```
$someCondition = false;
if ($someCondition === true) {
    function fn() {
        return 1;
    }
}
echo fn(); // triggers error
```

In this case, `fn()` will never be declared because `$someCondition` is not true.

**Example 2 - Function in Function Declaration**

```
function createFn() 
{
    function fn() {
        return 1;
    }
}
echo fn(); // triggers error
```

In this case, `fn` will only be declared once `createFn()` gets called. Note that subsequent calls to `createFn()` will trigger an error about Redeclaration of an Existing function.

You may also see this for a PHP built-in function. Try searching for the function in [the official manual](http://php.net/manual/en/funcref.php), and check what "extension" (PHP module) it belongs to, and what versions of PHP support it.

In case of a missing extension, install that extension and enable it in php.ini. Refer to the Installation Instructions in the PHP Manual for the extension your function appears in. You may also be able to enable or install the extension using your package manager (e.g. `apt` in Debian or Ubuntu, `yum` in Red Hat or CentOS), or a control panel in a shared hosting environment.

If the function was introduced in a newer version of PHP from what you are using, you may find links to alternative implementations in the manual or its comment section. If it has been removed from PHP, look for information about why, as it may no longer be necessary.

In case of missing includes, make sure to include the file declaring the function before calling the function.

In case of typos, fix the typo.

Related Questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Fatal+error%3A+Call+to+undefined+function

Answer (score 76):

#### Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_XXX

Happens when you have [`T_XXX` token](http://php.net/tokens) in unexpected place, unbalanced (superfluous) parentheses, use of short tag without activating it in php.ini, and many more.

Related Questions:

- Reference: [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18050071/367456)
- [Parse Error: syntax error: unexpected '{'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059753/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected)
- [Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected end of file in my PHP code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482527/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file-in-my-php-code)
- [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in - Fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992403/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-in-fix)
- [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762216/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected)

For further help see:

- http://phpcodechecker.com/ - Which does provide some more helpful explanations on your syntax woes.

Answer (score 74):

#### Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

This usually happens when using a function directly with `empty`.

Example:

```
if (empty(is_null(null))) {
  echo 'empty';
}
```

This is because [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) is a language construct and not a function, it cannot be called with an expression as its argument in PHP versions before 5.5.  Prior to PHP 5.5, the argument to `empty()` must be a *variable*, but an arbitrary expression (such as a return value of a function) is permissible in PHP 5.5+.

`empty`, despite its name, does not actually check if a variable is "empty". Instead, it checks if a variable doesn't exist, or `== false`. Expressions (like `is_null(null)` in the example) will always be deemed to exist, so here `empty` is only checking if it is equal to false. You could replace `empty()` here with `!`, e.g. `if (!is_null(null))`, or explicitly compare to false, e.g. `if (is_null(null) == false)`.

Related Questions:

- [Fatal error: Can't use function the return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872184/fatal-error-cant-use-function-return-value)

Answer (score 67):

#### MySQL: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ... at line ...

This error is often caused because you forgot to properly escape the data passed to a MySQL query.

An example of what **not** to do (the "Bad Idea"):

```
$query = "UPDATE `posts` SET my_text='{$_POST['text']}' WHERE id={$_GET['id']}";
mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

This code could be included in a page with a form to submit, with an URL such as http://example.com/edit.php?id=10 (to edit the post n°10)

What will happen if the submitted text contains single quotes? `$query` will end up with:

```
$query = "UPDATE `posts` SET my_text='I'm a PHP newbie' WHERE id=10';
```

And when this query is sent to MySQL, it will complain that the syntax is wrong, because there is an extra single quote in the middle.

To avoid such errors, you **MUST** always escape the data before use in a query.

Escaping data before use in a SQL query is also very important because if you don't, your script will be open to SQL injections. An SQL injection may cause alteration, loss or modification of a record, a table or an entire database. This is a very serious security issue!

Documentation:

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
- [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)
- [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string)
- [How does the SQL injection from the "Bobby Tables" XKCD comic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain)
- [SQL injection that gets around mysql_real_escape_string()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)

Comment: In addition, if you don't your site will be hacked by bots automatically

Comment: Or use a prepared sql query.

Answer (score 58):

#### Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE

In PHP 8.0 and above, the message is instead:

> syntax error, unexpected string content "", expecting "-" or identifier or variable or number

This error is most often encountered when attempting to reference an array value with a *quoted key* for interpolation inside a double-quoted string when the entire complex variable construct is not enclosed in `{}`.

#### The error case:

This will result in `Unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE`:

```
echo "This is a double-quoted string with a quoted array key in $array['key']";
//---------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^
```

#### Possible fixes:

In a double-quoted string, PHP will permit array key strings to be used *unquoted*, and will not issue an `E_NOTICE`.  So the above could be written as:

```
echo "This is a double-quoted string with an un-quoted array key in $array[key]";
//------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^
```

The entire complex array variable and key(s) can be enclosed in `{}`, in which case they *should* be quoted to avoid an `E_NOTICE`.  [The PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) recommends this syntax for complex variables.

```
echo "This is a double-quoted string with a quoted array key in {$array['key']}";
//--------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// Or a complex array property of an object:
echo "This is a a double-quoted string with a complex {$object->property->array['key']}";
```

Of course, the alternative to *any* of the above is to concatenate the array variable in instead of interpolating it:

```
echo "This is a double-quoted string with an array variable". $array['key'] . " concatenated inside.";
//----------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

For reference, see the section on **Variable Parsing** in [the PHP Strings manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

Answer (score 55):

#### Fatal error: Allowed memory size of XXX bytes exhausted (tried to allocate XXX bytes)

There is not enough memory to run your script. PHP has reached the memory limit and stops executing it. This error is fatal, the script stops. The value of the [memory limit](http://php.net/memory_limit) can be configured either in the `php.ini` file or by using `ini_set('memory_limit', '128 M');` in the script (which will overwrite the value defined in `php.ini`). The purpose of the memory limit is to prevent a single PHP script from gobbling up all the available memory and bringing the whole web server down.

The first thing to do is to minimise the amount of memory your script needs. For instance, if you're reading a large file into a variable or are fetching many records from a database and are storing them all in an array, that may use a lot of memory. Change your code to instead read the file line by line or fetch database records one at a time without storing them all in memory. This does require a bit of a conceptual awareness of what's going on behind the scenes and when data is stored in memory vs. elsewhere.

If this error occurred when your script was not doing memory-intensive work, you need to check your code to see whether there is a memory leak. The [`memory_get_usage`](http://php.net/manual/function.memory-get-usage.php) function is your friend.

Related Questions:

- [All "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of XXX bytes exhausted" Questions on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Fatal%20error:%20Allowed%20memory%20size%20of%20xxxx%20bytes%20exhausted)

Answer (score 48):

#### Notice: Use of undefined constant XXX - assumed 'XXX'

or, in PHP 7.2 or later:

#### Warning: Use of undefined constant XXX - assumed 'XXX' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

or, in PHP 8.0 or later:

#### Error: Undefined constant XXX

This occurs when a token is used in the code and appears to be a constant, but a constant by that name is not defined.

One of the most common causes of this notice is a failure to quote a string used as an associative array key.

For example:

```
// Wrong
echo $array[key];

// Right
echo $array['key'];
```

Another common cause is a missing `$` (dollar) sign in front of a variable name:

```
// Wrong
echo varName;

// Right
echo $varName;
```

Or perhaps you have misspelled some other constant or keyword:

```
// Wrong
$foo = fasle;

// Right
$foo = false;
```

It can also be a sign that a needed PHP extension or library is missing when you try to access a constant defined by that library.

Related Questions:

- [What does the PHP error message “Notice: Use of undefined constant” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941169/what-does-the-php-error-message-notice-use-of-undefined-constant-mean)

Comment: I would say the most common cause is forgetting $ in front of a variable, not arrays.

Answer (score 48):

#### Notice: Undefined variable

Happens when you try to use a variable that wasn't previously defined.

A typical example would be

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    // do something with item
    $counter++;
}
```

If you didn't define `$counter` before, the code above will trigger the notice.

The correct way is to set the variable before using it

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) {
    // do something with item
    $counter++;
}
```

Similarly, a variable is not accessible outside its scope, for example when using anonymous functions.

```
$prefix = "Blueberry";
$food = ["cake", "cheese", "pie"];
$prefixedFood = array_map(function ($food) {
  // Prefix is undefined
  return "${prefix} ${food}";
}, $food);
```

This should instead be passed using `use`

```
$prefix = "Blueberry";
$food = ["cake", "cheese", "pie"];
$prefixedFood = array_map(function ($food) use ($prefix) {
  return "${prefix} ${food}";
}, $food);
```

#### Notice: Undefined property

This error means much the same thing, but refers to a property of an object. Reusing the example above, this code would trigger the error because the `counter` property hasn't been set.

```
$obj = new stdclass;
$obj->property = 2342;
foreach ($items as $item) {
    // do something with item
    $obj->counter++;
}
```

Related Questions:

- [All PHP "Notice: Undefined Variable" Questions on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Notice%3A+Undefined+Variable+%5Bphp%5D)
- ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)
- [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-and-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where/16959577#16959577)

Answer (score 48):

#### Warning: *[function]*: failed to open stream: *[reason]*

It happens when you call a file usually by `include`, `require` or `fopen` and PHP couldn't find the file or have not enough permission to load the file.

This can happen for a variety of reasons :

- the file path is wrong
- the file path is relative
- include path is wrong
- permissions are too restrictive
- SELinux is in force
- and many more ...

One common mistake is to not use an absolute path. This can be easily solved by using a full path or [magic constants](http://php.net/manual/language.constants.predefined.php) like `__DIR__` or  `dirname(__FILE__)`:

```
include __DIR__ . '/inc/globals.inc.php';
```

or:

```
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/inc/globals.inc.php';
```

Ensuring the right path is used is one step in troubleshooting these issues, this can also be related to non-existing files, rights of the filesystem preventing access or open basedir restrictions by PHP itself.

The best way to solve this problem quickly is to follow the troubleshooting checklist below.

Related Questions:

- [Troubleshooting checklist: Failed to open stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Related Errors:

- [Warning: open_basedir restriction in effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12772244#12772244)

Answer (score 47):

#### Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM

The scope resolution operator is also called "Paamayim Nekudotayim" from the Hebrew פעמיים נקודתיים‎. which means "double colon".

This error typically happens if you inadvertently put `::` in your code.

Related Questions:

- Reference: [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18050071/367456)
- [What do two colons mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903564/what-do-two-colons-mean-in-php)
- [What's the difference between :: (double colon) and -> (arrow) in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173501/in-php-whats-the-difference-between-double-colon-and-arrow)
- [Unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM, expecting T_NS_Separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734823/unexpected-t-paamayim-nekudotayim-expecting-t-ns-separator)

Documentation:

- [Scope Resolution Operator (::)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php)

Comment: The easiest way to trigger this error is running `a()::b;` or `$a=::;`.

Answer (score 44):

#### Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class *[class name]*

#### Fatal error: Cannot redeclare *[function name]*

This means you're either using the same function/class name twice and need to rename one of them,  or it is because you have used `require` or `include` where you should be using `require_once` or `include_once`.

When a class or a function is declared in PHP, it is immutable, and cannot later be declared with a new value.

Consider the following code:

*class.php*

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

*index.php*

```
<?php

function do_stuff()
{
   require 'class.php';
   $obj = new MyClass;
   $obj->doSomething();
}

do_stuff();
do_stuff();
```

The second call to `do_stuff()` will produce the error above. By changing `require` to `require_once`, we can be certain that the file that contains the definition of `MyClass` will only be loaded once, and the error will be avoided.

Comment: Is it worth mentioning using autoloading, and standards such as [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) or even the now deprecated [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) pretty much get rid of this by saving you from needing to use require/include yourself (bar a few bizarre edge cases).

Answer (score 37):

#### Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Possible scenario

I can't seem to find where my code has gone wrong. Here is my full error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE on line x

What I am trying

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM dealer WHERE id="'$id.'"';
```

Answer

**Parse error:** A problem with the syntax of your program, such as leaving a semicolon off of the end of a statement or, like the case above, missing the `.` operator. The interpreter stops running your program when it encounters a parse error.

In simple words this is a syntax error, meaning that there is something in your code stopping it from being parsed correctly and therefore running.

**What you should do** is check carefully at the lines around where the error is for any simple mistakes.

That error message means that in line x of the file, the PHP interpreter was expecting to see an open parenthesis but instead, it encountered something called `T_VARIABLE`. That `T_VARIABLE` thing is called a `token`. It's the PHP interpreter's way of expressing different fundamental parts of programs. When the interpreter reads in a program, it translates what you've written into a list of tokens. Wherever you put a variable in your program, there is a`T_VARIABLE` token in the interpreter's list.

[**Good read: List of Parser Tokens**](http://php.net/tokens)

So make sure you enable at least `E_PARSE` in your `php.ini`. Parse errors should not exist in production scripts.

I always recommended to add the following statement, while coding:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

[PHP error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Also, a good idea to use an IDE which will let you know parse errors while typing. You can use:

1. [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/downloads/) (a fine piece of beauty, free software) (the best in my opinion)
2. [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) (uncle Gordon love this: P, paid plan, contains proprietary and free software)
3. [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/heliosr) (beauty and the beast, free software)

Related Questions:

- Reference: [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18050071/367456)

Answer (score 36):

#### Notice: Uninitialized string offset: `*`

As the name indicates, such type of error occurs, when you are most likely trying to iterate over or find a value from an array with a non-existing key.

Consider you, are trying to show every letter from `$string`

```
$string = 'ABCD'; 
for ($i=0, $len = strlen($string); $i <= $len; $i++){
    echo "$string[$i] \n"; 
}
```

The above example will generate ([online demo](https://eval.in/38350)):

```
A
B
C
D
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 4 in XXX on line X
```

And, as soon as the script finishes echoing `D` you'll get the error, because inside the `for()` loop, you have told PHP to show you the from first to fifth string character from `'ABCD'` Which, exists, but since the loop starts to count from `0` and echoes `D` by the time it reaches to `4`, it will throw an offset error.

Similar Errors:

- [Illegal string offset 'option 1'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14086365/367456)

Answer (score 36):

#### Notice: Trying to get property of non-object error

Happens when you try to access a property of an object while there is no object.

A typical example for a non-object notice would be

```
$users = json_decode('[{"name": "hakre"}]');
echo $users->name; # Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
```

In this case, `$users` is an array (so not an object) and it does not have any properties.

This is similar to accessing a non-existing index or key of an array (see [Notice: Undefined Index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12770836/367456)).

This example is much simplified. Most often such a notice signals an unchecked return value, e.g. when a library returns `NULL` if an object does not exists or just an unexpected non-object value (e.g. in an Xpath result, JSON structures with unexpected format, XML with unexpected format etc.) but the code does not check for such a condition.

As those non-objects are often processed further on, often a fatal-error happens next on calling an object method on a non-object (see: [Fatal error: Call to a member function ... on a non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12769983/367456)) halting the script.

It can be easily prevented by checking for error conditions and/or that a variable matches an expectation. Here such a notice with a **DOMXPath** example:

```
$result  = $xpath->query("//*[@id='detail-sections']/div[1]");
$divText = $result->item(0)->nodeValue; # Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
```

The problem is accessing the `nodeValue` property (field) of the first item while it has not been checked if it exists or not in the `$result` collection. Instead it pays to make the code more explicit by assigning variables to the objects the code operates on:

```
$result  = $xpath->query("//*[@id='detail-sections']/div[1]");
$div     = $result->item(0);
$divText = "-/-";
if (is_object($div)) {
    $divText = $div->nodeValue;
}
echo $divText;
```

Related errors:

- [Notice: Undefined Index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12770836/367456)
- [Fatal error: Call to a member function ... on a non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12769983/367456)

Comment: `json_decode` now returns an instance of `stdclass` by default, so the example code *would* actually work.

Comment: @HugoZink: It actually does (and always did) return an array for that example: https://3v4l.org/SUDe0 - Also can you please provide reference for your writing that *"`json_decode` now returns an instance of `stdclass` by default"* ? I can't find that in the changelog.

Comment: According to the PHP manual's page on [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), by default, the `assoc` parameter is set to false. This parameter decides whether the function returns a `stdclass` instead of an associative array.

Comment: `json_decode('[{"name": "hakre"}]', true)` will return an array, otherwise a `stdclass` object

Answer (score 30):

#### Warning: open_basedir restriction in effect

This warning can appear with various functions that are related to file and directory access. It warns about a configuration issue.

When it appears, it means that access has been forbidden to some files.

The warning itself does not break anything, but most often a script does not properly work if file-access is prevented.

The fix is normally to change the [PHP configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.php), the related setting is called [`open_basedir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir).

Sometimes the wrong file or directory names are used, the fix is then to use the right ones.

Related Questions:

- [open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths)
- [All PHP "Warning: open_basedir restriction in effect" Querstions on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+Warning%3A+open_basedir+restriction+in+effect)

Comment: This occurs most often on a shared host, people don't usually lock themselves out of directories :-)

Answer (score 30):

#### Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

This error comes in two variatians:

#### Variation 1

```
$arr = [1, 2, 3];
```

This array initializer syntax was only introduced in PHP 5.4; it will raise a parser error on versions before that. If possible, upgrade your installation or use the old syntax:

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3);
```

See also [this example](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-83) from the manual.

#### Variation 2

```
$suffix = explode(',', 'foo,bar')[1];
```

Array dereferencing function results was also introduced in PHP 5.4. If it's not possible to upgrade you need to use a (temporary) variable:

```
$parts = explode(',', 'foo,bar');
$suffix = $parts[1];
```

See also [this example](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-89) from the manual.

Answer (score 24):

#### Warning: *[function]* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

(A more general variation of [Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12770072#12770072))

Resources are a [type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) in PHP (like strings, integers or objects). A resource is an opaque blob with no inherently meaningful value of its own. A resource is specific to and defined by a certain set of PHP functions or extension. For instance, the Mysql extension [defines two resource types](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.resources.php):

> There are two resource types used in the MySQL module. The first one is the link identifier for a database connection, the second a resource which holds the result of a query.

The cURL extension defines another [two resource types](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.resources.php):

> ... a cURL handle and a cURL multi handle.

When `var_dump`ed, the values look like this:

```
$resource = curl_init();
var_dump($resource);

resource(1) of type (curl)
```

That's all most resources are, a numeric identifier (`(1)`) of a certain type (`(curl)`).

You carry these resources around and pass them to different functions for which such a resource means something. Typically these functions allocate certain data in the background and a resource is just a reference which they use to keep track of this data internally.

---

The "**... expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given**" error is typically the result of an unchecked operation that was supposed to create a resource, but returned `false` instead. For instance, the [`fopen` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) has this description:

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns a file pointer resource on success, or `FALSE` on error.

So in this code, `$fp` will either be a `resource(x) of type (stream)` or `false`:

```
$fp = fopen(...);
```

If you do not check whether the `fopen` operation succeed or failed and hence whether `$fp` is a valid resource or `false` and pass `$fp` to another function which expects a resource, you may get the above error:

```
$fp   = fopen(...);
$data = fread($fp, 1024);

Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

You always need to error check the return value of functions which are trying to allocate a resource ***and may fail***:

```
$fp = fopen(...);

if (!$fp) {
    trigger_error('Failed to allocate resource');
    exit;
}

$data = fread($fp, 1024);
```

Related Errors:

- [Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12770072#12770072)

Answer (score 23):

#### Warning: Illegal string offset 'XXX'

This happens when you try to access an array element with the square bracket syntax, but you're doing this on a string, and not on an array, so the operation clearly *doesn't make sense*.

Example:

```
$var = "test";
echo $var["a_key"];
```

If you think the variable should be an array, see where it comes from and fix the problem there.

Answer (score 21):

#### Code doesn't run/what looks like parts of my PHP code are output

If you see no result from your PHP code whatsoever and/or you are seeing parts of your literal PHP source code output in the webpage, you can be pretty sure that your PHP isn't actually getting executed. If you use View Source in your browser, you're probably seeing the whole PHP source code file as is. Since PHP code is embedded in `<?php ?>` tags, the browser will try to interpret those as HTML tags and the result may look somewhat confused.

To actually run your PHP scripts, you need:

- a web server which executes your script
- to set the file extension to .php, otherwise the web server won't interpret it as such*
- to access your .php file via the web server

<sub>* Unless you reconfigure it, everything can be configured.</sub>

This last one is particularly important. Just double clicking the file will likely open it in your browser using an address such as:

```
file://C:/path/to/my/file.php
```

This is completely bypassing any web server you may have running and the file is not getting interpreted. You need to visit the URL of the file on your web server, likely something like:

```
http://localhost/my/file.php
```

You may also want to check whether you're using short open tags `<?` instead of `<?php` and your PHP configuration has turned short open tags off.

Also see [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page)

Answer (score 21):

#### Warning: Array to string conversion

#### Notice: Array to string conversion

*(A notice until PHP 7.4, since PHP 8.0 a warning)*

This simply happens if you try to treat an array as a string:

```
$arr = array('foo', 'bar');

echo $arr;  // Notice: Array to string conversion
$str = 'Something, ' . $arr;  // Notice: Array to string conversion
```

An array cannot simply be `echo`'d or concatenated with a string, because the result is not well defined. PHP will use the string "Array" in place of the array, and trigger the notice to point out that that's probably not what was intended and that you should be checking your code here. You probably want something like this instead:

```
echo $arr[0];  // displays foo
$str = 'Something ' . join(', ', $arr); //displays Something, foo, bar
```

Or loop the array:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo "array $key = $value";
    // displays first: array 0 = foo
    // displays next:  array 1 = bar
}
```

If this notice appears somewhere you don't expect, it means a variable which you thought is a string is actually an array. That means you have a bug in your code which makes this variable an array instead of the string you expect.

Answer (score 20):

#### Deprecated: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated

String offsets and array elements could be accessed by curly braces `{}` prior to PHP 7.4.0:

```
$string = 'abc';
echo $string{0};  // a

$array = [1, 2, 3];
echo $array{0};  // 1
```

This has been deprecated since PHP 7.4.0 and generates a warning:

> Deprecated: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated

You must use square brackets `[]` to access string offsets and array elements:

```
$string = 'abc';
echo $string[0];  // a

$array = [1, 2, 3];
echo $array[0];  // 1
```

The [RFC for this change](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_curly_braces_array_access) links to a PHP [script](https://gist.github.com/theodorejb/763b83a43522b0fc1755a537663b1863) which attempts to fix this mechanically.

Answer (score 19):

#### Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'name'@'host'

This warning shows up when you connect to a MySQL/MariaDB server with invalid or missing credentials (username/password). So this is typically *not* a code problem, but a server configuration issue.

- See the manual page on [`mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pw")`](http://php.net/mysql_connect) for examples.
- Check that you actually used a `$username` and `$password`.

  - It's uncommon that you gain access using no password - which is what happened when the Warning: said `(using password: NO)`.
  - Only the local test server usually allows to connect with username `root`, no password, and the `test` database name.
  - You can test if they're **really correct** using the command line client:
    `mysql --user="username" --password="password" testdb`
  - Username and password are *case-sensitive* and whitespace is *not* ignored. If your password contains meta characters like `$`, escape them, or put the password in [single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php).
  - Most shared hosting providers predeclare mysql accounts in relation to the unix user account (sometimes just prefixes or extra numeric suffixes). See the docs for a pattern or documentation, and CPanel or whatever interface for setting a password.
  - See the MySQL manual on [Adding user accounts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html) using the command line. When connected as *admin user* you can issue a query like:
     `CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';`
  - Or use [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/) or [WorkBench](http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/) or any other graphical tool to create, check or correct account details.
  - If you can't fix your credentials, then asking the internet to "please help" will have no effect. Only you and your hosting provider have permissions and sufficient access to diagnose and fix things.
- Verify that you **could reach** the database server, using the host name given by your provider:
   `ping dbserver.hoster.example.net`

  - Check this from a SSH console directly on your webserver. Testing from your local development client to your shared hosting server is rarely meaningful.
  - Often you just want the server name to be `"localhost"`, which normally utilizes a local named socket when available. Othertimes you can try `"127.0.0.1"` as fallback.
  - Should your MySQL/MariaDB server listen on a different port, then use `"servername:3306"`.
  - If that fails, then there's a perhaps a firewall issue. (Off-topic, not a programming question. No remote guess-helping possible.)
- When using **constants** like e.g. `DB_USER` or `DB_PASSWORD`, check that they're actually [defined](http://php.net/define).

  - If you get a `"Warning: Access defined for 'DB_USER'@'host'"` and a `"Notice: use of undefined constant 'DB_PASS'"`, then that's your problem.
  - Verify that your e.g. `xy/db-config.php` was actually included and whatelse.
- Check for correctly set **[`GRANT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html) permissions**.

  - It's not sufficient to have a `username`+`password` pair.
  - Each MySQL/MariaDB account can have an attached set of permissions.
  - Those can restrict which databases you are allowed to connect to, from which client/server the connection may originate from, and which queries are permitted.
  - The "Access denied" warning thus may as well show up for [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/mysql_query) calls, if you don't have permissions to `SELECT` from a specific table, or `INSERT`/`UPDATE`, and more commonly `DELETE` anything.
  - You can [adapt account permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016505/mysql-grant-all-privileges-on-database) when connected per command line client using the *admin account* with a query like:
     `GRANT ALL ON yourdb.* TO 'username'@'localhost';`
- If the warning shows up first with `Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost'` then you may have a [php.ini-preconfigured account/password pair](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php).

  - Check that `mysql.default_user=` and `mysql.default_password=` have meaningful values.
  - Oftentimes this is a provider-configuration. So contact their support for mismatches.
- Find the documentation of your shared hosting provider:

  - e.g. [HostGator](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/sql-errors), [GoDaddy](https://www.godaddy.com/help/connecting-to-mysql-using-php-216), [1and1](https://hilfe-center.1und1.de/hosting/skript--und-programmiersprachen-c10082634/php-c10082686/problemloesung-c10085144/haeufige-mysql-fehlermeldungen-in-php-skripten-oder--programmen-a10791915.html), [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/access-denied-for-installing-mysql), [BlueHost](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/2213), [DreamHost](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/MySQL), [MediaTemple](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204642990/why-can't-i-connect-to-my-mysql-database-from-php), [ixWebhosting](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/community-support/databases/1045-access-denied-for-user-mysql-error), [lunarhosting](http://www.lunarforums.com/php-and-mysql-support/trouble-connecting-to-my-sql-db/), or just google yours´.
  - Else consult your webhosting provider through their support channels.
- Note that you may also have *depleted the available connection pool*. You'll get access denied warnings for too many concurrent connections. (You have to investigate the setup. That's an off-topic server configuration issue, not a programming question.)
- Your libmysql client *version may not be compatible* with the database server. Normally MySQL and MariaDB servers can be reached with PHPs compiled in driver. If you have a custom setup, or an outdated PHP version, and a much newer database server, or significantly outdated one - then the version mismatch may prevent connections. (No, you have to investigate yourself. Nobody can guess your setup).

More references:

- [Serverfault: mysql access denied for 'root'@'name of the computer'](https://superuser.com/questions/584106/mysql-access-denied-for-rootname-of-the-computer)
- [Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782452/warning-mysql-connect-access-denied)
- [Warning: mysql_select_db() Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531530/warning-mysql-select-db-access-denied-for-user-localhost-using-password)
- [Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' with PHPMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482970/1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-no)

> Btw, you probably don't want to use [`mysql_*` functions anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). Newcomers often migrate to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php), which however is just as tedious. Instead read up on [PDO and prepared statements](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).
>    `$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb", "username", "password");`

Comment: mysql allows auto-connect via php-ini settings, then the same error message is given with the different command prefixed, e.g. *"Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in ..."* - just noting.

Comment: Ha, totally forgot about that! (Probably last used that with PHP3 or so..)

Answer (score 14):

#### Warning: Division by zero

The warning message 'Division by zero' is one of the most commonly asked questions among new PHP developers.  This error will not cause an exception, therefore, some developers will occasionally suppress the warning by adding the error suppression operator @ before the expression.  For example:

```
$value = @(2 / 0);
```

But, like with any warning, the best approach would be to track down the cause of the warning and resolve it.  The cause of the warning is going to come from any instance where you attempt to divide by 0, a variable equal to 0, or a variable which has not been assigned (because NULL == 0) because the result will be 'undefined'.

To correct this warning, you should rewrite your expression to check that the value is not 0, if it is, do something else.  If the value is zero you either should not divide, or you should change the value to 1 and then divide so the division results in the equivalent of having divided only by the additional variable.

```
if ( $var1 == 0 ) { // check if var1 equals zero
    $var1 = 1; // var1 equaled zero so change var1 to equal one instead
    $var3 = ($var2 / $var1); // divide var1/var2 ie. 1/1
} else {
    $var3 = ($var2 / $var1); // if var1 does not equal zero, divide
}
```

Related Questions:

- [warning: division by zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539002/warning-division-by-zero)
- [Warning: Division By Zero Working on PHP and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592602/warning-division-by-zero-working-on-php-and-mysql)
- [Division by zero error in WordPress Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667601/division-by-zero-error-in-wordpress-theme)
- [How to suppress the “Division by zero” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731710/how-to-suppress-the-division-by-zero-error-and-set-the-result-to-null-for-the)
- [How to catch a division by zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071067/how-to-catch-a-division-by-zero)

Comment: Setting to 1 if it was 0 will stop the error but is this really any better than the suppression you said shouldn't be used (which I agree with)? I'd suggest most times it'd be likely some other message or value would be returned.

Comment: For this example, if `$var1` does == 0 then you can just set `$var3` to `$var2`. Even if not doing that, the else is not needed at all as the assignment is the same in both cases so no else and assign outside the `if`

Answer (score 9):

#### Strict Standards: Non-static method *[<class>::<method>]* should not be called statically

Occurs when you try to call a non-static method on a class as it was static, and you also have the `E_STRICT` flag in your `error_reporting()` settings.

Example :

```
class HTML {
   public function br() {
      echo '<br>';
   }
}
```

`HTML::br()` or `$html::br()`

You can actually avoid this error by not adding `E_STRICT` to `error_reporting()`, eg

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT);
```

since as for PHP 5.4.0 and above, `E_STRICT` is included in `E_ALL` [[ref](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migrating5.errorrep.php)]. But that is not adviceable. The solution is to define your intended static function as actual `static` :

```
public static function br() {
  echo '<br>';
}
```

or call the function conventionally :

```
$html = new HTML();
$html->br();
```

---

Related questions :

- [How can I solve "Non-static method xxx:xxx() should not be called statically in PHP 5.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768576/how-can-i-solve-non-static-method-xxxxxx-should-not-be-called-statically-in)

Answer (score 9):

#### Fatal error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to a string

It means that you are not executing your anonymous function (or a closure).

An error will be thrown for this example using arrow functions:

```
echo $fn = fn($x = 42) => $x;
```

Or for any anonymous function

```
echo function($x = 42) { return $x; };
```

To resolve this error you need to execute the closure.

```
echo $fn = (fn($x = 42) => $x)(30); // take notice of the 2 sets of brackets

echo (function($x = 42) { return $x; })(30);
```

This kind of syntax is called [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression) and it was [added in PHP 7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35044545/1839439).

Answer (score 8):

#### HTTP Error 500 - Internal server error

The HTTP status code 500 and the typical Apache or browser warning is a very broad message. It's not the actual error. To figure out if it's a webserver misconfiguration (`.htaccess`) or a PHP fatal error, you have to look at the **`error.log`**.

[image: Apache error page: "More information about this error may be available in the server error log."]

You can typically find the webservers log under:

- `/var/log/apache2` on Linux servers, often used for local and virtual hosts.
- `/var/www/_user12345_/logs` or similar on shared hosting plans.
   Usually there's a `logs/` directory alongside each `htdocs/` folder.
- `C:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log` for [WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713001/where-can-i-find-the-wamp-error-log)/[XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719549/where-does-phps-error-log-reside-in-xampp) distributions of Apache+PHP.
- Alternatively just use a file search feature to locate anything called "error.log".
  Or look into your Apache `httpd.conf` and its `ErrorLog` directive.
- `/var/log/nginx/nginx_error.log` for [NGINX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706111/where-can-i-find-the-error-logs-of-nginx-using-fastcgi-and-django).
- `C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles` for [IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426375/where-can-i-find-the-iis-logs).
- Luckily this is uncommon still, but `journalctl -r -u apache2.service` could also hold parts of the log on Linux setups.

It's a text file. Search for the entry most closely matching the error time, and use the significant part of the error message (from "PHP Error: …" until "in line…") for further googling.

> `[Mon 22:10] [:error] [pid 12345] [client 127.0.0.1] FastCGI: server "/fcgi/p73" stderr: PHP message:`**`PHP Error: Unfiltered input`**`variable $_JSON['pokestop_lng'] in filyfile.php on line 845`

For FPM setups you will often just see fatal PHP errors here. Whereas older mod_php (shared hosting) configurations often mix in warnings and notices (which usually are also worth inspecting).

If not configured to use the system or Apache logging mechanism, you may also want to look at [PHP's error.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel). Generally it's simpler to leave the defaults and just enable `error_display` + `error_reporting` to reveal the concrete error. The HTTP 500 catch-all page after all is just a variation of [PHP's white screen of death](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death).

See also:

- [500 Internal Server Error for php file not for html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693391/500-internal-server-error-for-php-file-not-for-html)
- [How can I make PHP display the error instead of giving me 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730/how-can-i-make-php-display-the-error-instead-of-giving-me-500-internal-server-er)
- [How can I display and log PHP errors on IIS7?](https://serverfault.com/questions/19561/how-can-i-display-and-log-php-errors-on-iis7)
- [How to Fix the 500 Internal Server Error in WordPress](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-internal-server-error-in-wordpress/)

Answer (score 7):

#### Fatal error: [TraitA] and [TraitB] define the same property ([$x]) in the composition of [ClassC]

Occurs when a class attempts to [`use` multiple Traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.multiple), where two or more of those Traits have [defined a property](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.properties) by the same name, and with the property having differing initial values.

Example:

```php
<?php
trait TraitA
{
    public $x = 'a';
}
trait TraitB
{
    public $x = 'b';
}
class ClassC
{
    use TraitA, TraitB;
}
```

**Problematic:** While it's possible to resolve conflicts between [competing methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.conflict), there is currently no syntax that would resolve a conflict between two competing properties. The only solution at this time is to [refactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring); i.e., avoid a conflict between property names that produces a fatal error.

---

Related Questions:

- [PHP Traits: How to resolve a property name conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41679384/php-traits-how-to-resolve-a-property-name-conflict)
- [Traits - property conflict with parent class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158392/traits-property-conflict-with-parent-class)

Comment: Note that this also happens when TraitA::$x and TraitB::$x are the same value(say 'a') but TraitA::$a is public and TraitB::$a is private or protected

Answer (score 6):

#### Warning: *function*() expects parameter *X* to be boolean (or integer, string, etc)

If the wrong type of parameter is passed to a function – and PHP cannot convert it automatically – a warning is thrown. This warning identifies which parameter is the problem, and what data type is expected. The solution: change the indicated parameter to the correct data type.

---

For example this code:

```
echo substr(["foo"], 23);
```

Results in this output:

> PHP Warning:  substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Answer (score 5):

#### Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Self-explanatory; the parameter passed to the `count()` function has to be something that is countable, usually an array.

The likely problem is that a scalar value such as a string or integer was passed, or an object that doesn't implement the `Countable` interface. Using `var_dump()` on the variable in question can show whether or not this is the case.

Answer (score 4):

### Fatal error: Maximum execution time of XX seconds exceeded

Every PHP page request or script invocation measures how long *PHP code* has been executing. If a configured limit is reached, the script is aborted with this message.

Note that the time generally *doesn't* include things that happen "outside of" PHP, such as time waiting for results from the database, or external programs executed with `shell_exec`, etc. The exception is when PHP is running on Windows, where the time measured is "clock time" and *does* include these external wait times.

**Common causes**

- **Infinite loops.** An incorrectly written `while`, `do...while` or `for` loop  may never complete, meaning PHP is running continuously forever. Even a `foreach` loop can be infinite, for instance if looping over an [Iterator object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) or [generator function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.php).
- **Large data sets.** Even if your loop is not infinite, if it is doing a lot of work, it may take too long to complete if it is processing a large number of results.

**Changing the limit**

If you know that you have a slow process, you can configure the time limit:

- In php.ini, using the [max_execution_time setting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time).
- While the script is running, using the [set_time_limit function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php). Note that calling this resets the measured time to zero, so `set_time_limit(10);` means "allow 10 *more* seconds, regardless of how long the script has already taken".

Both mechanisms should be given a number of seconds, or the special value `0` which means "no limit". Setting "no limit" is most useful for command-line scripts which you genuinely intend to run forever in the background; for web pages, it is better to set some finite value, even if it is very large, to prevent bugs in your code causing the entire system to become unresponsive.

Answer (score 2):

#### Fatal error: Undefined class constant

This error means that you have attempted to use a [class constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) that does not exist. Unlike other "undefined" notices and warnings, this is a fatal error and will stop the script immediately.

The first thing to be checked should be typographic errors. Confirm the constant is defined in the class, and that it is called using the appropriate namespace. Confirm also that all appropriate files have been included to resolve the constant.

Answer (score 2):

#### Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: some_function(): Argument #1 must be of type x, y given

This error explains itself. Your code attempted to call `some_function()` and passed the wrong type of data as one of the arguments. For example:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

function multiply(int $x, int $y) { return $x * $y; }

echo multiply("3", 4);
```

Because the called functions first argument is with the `int` scalar type, and the call is in a file which has strict types enabled (`stict_types=1`), it type-errors when passing a `string` to it:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: multiply(): Argument #1 ($x) must be of type integer, string given in...

This [example on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/SJvqd).

Answer (score 1):

#### Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, <type> given

This warning is shown when the type of the first variable in the *foreach* expression **isn't** an `array` or `object`.

Example 1

```
# Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given
$x = null;
foreach($x as $v) {
}
```

Example 2

```
# Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given
$x = 'abc';
foreach($x as $v) {
}
```

These are the two most common examples.

1. Ensure that the variable you want to iterate on is not null.
2. Ensuer that the type of this variable is `array` or `object`.
3. If you want to iterate through each character of a string, check [PHP - iterate on string characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601032/php-iterate-on-string-characters).